# SELECT * FROM table WHERE (value in cell as array) = $searchid

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, explode

I've got a db_table where some cells contain comma separated arrays to link them to all the corresponding rows in a different table column, like [846,1400,1657].

So how do i select all rows where that cell has one matching value in the array?

```
$result = "";
$searchid = $_POST['id'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Company WHERE City/*<-the array*/ LIKE '%$searchid%'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($count == 0){
    $result .= "no companies";
} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $name = $row['Name'];
        $result .= "<div class=\"result\">$name </div>";

    }
}

echo $result;
```

This gives all companies with $searchid, but if $searchid = 25, it will return the ones with 25 in that column as well as those with for example 250 and 725. :/

Without the wildcards tho:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Company WHERE City/*<-the array*/ = '$searchid'");
```

will return the rows with only $searchid in that cell, for example if $searchid = 25 a cell with [25] and not one with [25,456] or [12,13,25]

I've goggled for 48 hours and tried everything i found, think this should be an easy one to crack. 
What have i missed???

Comment: You can try using the [`IN Operator`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx) - `WHERE (expr|column) IN ('value1','value2',...)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think you can't combine `LIKE` with the `IN` operator but I may be wrong.

Comment: Your database design is rather poor.  It appears that there is a many-to-many relationship between Company and City entities.  In this case, have a third table that would associate each company with the city it is in.  Then, join the tables in your query.

Comment: @DRD The relation is more like this-to-many, julst like with country and cities.

Comment: It seems that one company could be in many cities and one city could have many companies.  No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function might work for this one. Here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM Company WHERE FIND_IN_SET('25', City) > 0
```

The example assumes that the `City` column is the one with the comma-separated list; I think that's what your question states.

Comment: That did the trick! 
Thanks a bunch! 
One question tho, why is the "> 0" necessary?

Comment: If the value of City is `'13,250,25,40'` then `FIND_IN_SET('25', City)` will return 3 because 25 is the third item in the comma-delimited list. If 25 isn't found in the comma-delimited list, FIND_IN_SET will return zero. So the "> 0" just means '25' was found somewhere in the list. Hope that makes sense :)  Also - if this is still working for you could you kindly accept my answer? That way others with similar questions will know that it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, that clarifies it. 
Sorry, new to this site, accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the like statement :

```
SELECT * FROM Company WHERE City LIKE "%25%";
```

Obviously this would select ones with 250 in too but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do split in mysql, you should have used a transitional table :

```
city_company
------------
id_city
id_company
```

Where you could have stored all these relations.

Though you could use `like` for a quick dirty hack.
Here is how you could do it :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Company WHERE concat(',',City,',') LIKE '%,$searchid,%'");
```